# How to get three div in one line

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to align three div in one line with a little space between first div and second div and last div using bootstrap as you see in the picture : 
[image]

I try with this code :

```
    <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                     <img src="img/emo_positif.png')}}">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-7">
                     <div class="square1"></div>

                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-3">
                     <img src="img/emo_negative.png')}}">
                   </div>
</div>
```

but it shows me a big space between the div

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this. One for example, would be to simply add `display: flex` to your `row`.

Comment: Yannick jansen, Did you check my answer / [pen](https://codepen.io/carloluis/pen/GQzbLP/)?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Bootstrap 3](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css):

```css
.row {
  height: 24px;
}
.row > div {
  height: 100%;
}
.square {
  background: pink;
}
.square1 {
  background: #01a8ff;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 square">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="square1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 square">
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this [Pen](https://codepen.io/carloluis/pen/GQzbLP/).
Read the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-example-basic).

Answer (score 0):

For making the three division in same line . There are many ways. For better UX use `display:flex` in css for the parent division

Thanks